# HTML Input file control doesn't allow to upload file more than 5 MB

Tags: asp.net

I have a HTMLFile Input control on my .aspx page but it doesn't allow to uploas file more than 5 MB.

Thanx

Answer (score 1):

There is a limit to the uploaded files.

Read this for details: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479405.aspx

You can change the limit on web.config

```
<httpRuntime  maxRequestLength="4096" ... >
```